# Neo4j create node if not exist on relationship creation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

With Neo4J, when creating a relationship, I would like to create a node if it does not exist. I can do this using MERGE, but I would like the created node to be of a different type. Is there a way to check if the node exists and create a different node if not.

My current request:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name:'Jon'})
MERGE (b:City {name: 'Paris'})
CREATE (a)-[:work]->(b)
```

Here we assume that the person exists in all cases, but the city not necessarily.
This request works and creates a new city if it does not exist.

My problem is that I want to keep a track of the new city by giving them the type "NewCity" instead of "City".

Comment: If Paris does not exists yet, then you should still create a label City for Paris, but add another label NewCity so you can keep track of the new cities that are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would write it like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person {name:'Jon'})
MERGE (b:City {name: 'Paris'})
ON CREATE
    SET b:NewCity
ON MATCH
    REMOVE b:NewCity // <-- spoiler alert: this does NOT work :(
CREATE (a)-[:work]->(b)
```

You need to keep the `City` label when you first create the node, otherwise the next time the query runs, `MERGE` won't match the node anymore.

Unfortunately, `ON MATCH REMOVE b:NewCity` [is not supported](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6172), so you have to introduce an extra SET that gets removed afterwards:

```
MERGE (b:City {name: 'Paris'})
ON CREATE
    SET b:NewCity
ON MATCH
    SET b.temp = ''
WITH *
CALL { WITH b
  WITH b WHERE b.temp IS NOT NULL
  REMOVE b.temp
  REMOVE b:NewCity
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just add the ON CREATE part on my request and it's done as I want.